# Q: Display grouped and combined boxplot in a single plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to display grouped boxplot and combined boxplot into one plot. Take the `iris` data for instance:

```
data(iris)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
p1
```

[image: boxplot]

I am trying to compare overall distribution with distributions within each categories. So is there a way to display a boxplot of all samples on the left of these three grouped boxplots?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `rbind` a new version of `iris`, where `Species` equals `"All"` for all rows, to `iris` before piping to `ggplot`

```
p1 <- iris %>% 
        rbind(iris %>% mutate(Species = 'All')) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
          geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Now I get it, basically I create a new category 'all' by using all the data. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can just create a column for all species as follows:

```
iris = iris %>% mutate(all = "All Species")
p1 <- ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=all, y=Sepal.Length))
p1
```

[image: output]

Comment: It works! I guess I need to know more about ggplot2 . Thanks a lot!